# Error: A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'num'

Tags: dart

I recently started dart programing, I encountered a issue while doing it,
I was doing it by referring this website https://hackmd.io/@kuzmapetrovich/S1x90jWGP

```
Error: A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'num'.
```

My code :

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print('Enter a number');
  var num1 = stdin.readLineSync();
  var num2= 100-num1;
}
```

can anyone tell whats the issue and how to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `stdin.readLineSync()` reads your console input and will store it to `num1` of type `var`. As you can see in the [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-io/Stdin/readLineSync.html), `stdin.readLineSync()` returns a `String?`.
Because the data type of `var` variables is resolved during runtime, `num1` will be of type `String?` after assigning the console input to it.

**So the problem of your code is, that you try to subtract 100 from a string, which is not possible.**

To solve this issue you should better convert your input into a numerical type, like `int` or `double`. But be careful! Your input could also contain character that can't be converted to a number. One solution could look like following:

```
void main() {
  print('Enter a number');
  
  var input = stdin.readLineSync();
  var num1 = double.parse(input);

  if (num1 != null){
    var num2 = 100 - num1;
  }else{
    // num1 could not be converted to a double
    // handle exception here
  }
  
}
```

For the beginning, I recommend you to use data types in your code instead of `var` and `val`. Maybe reading something about [dart's type system](https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you can parse String into

int
`var num2 = 100 - int.parse(num1!);`
or double
`var num2 = 100 - double.parse(num1!);`